# When do I need to call watchers.dispatch() in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a small application I am building that is very similar to the example [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#loops).

I am using `Dart SDK version 0.5.9.0_r22879`

The main difference is that I update the results via an AJAX request, and I only make this request when Enter is pressed in my input control.

In my code, the results list does not render unless I explicitly call `watchers.dispatch()`, as discussed in the 2nd example [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#one-way-binding).

Why? It is not clear when I would have to explicitly call `watchers.dispatch()`, and when it would happen automatically, as in the template example.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myapp.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My App</h1>

    <div id="seach-box-container">
      <input type="text" name="search-box" id="search-box" placeholder="Search" bind-value="searchText" />
    </div>

    <div id="results-container">
      <template instantiate="if noMatches"><span>No matches</span></template>
      <template instantiate="if !noMatches"><span>{{results.length}} entries:</span></template>
      <div id="app-entries">
        <ul>
          <template iterate='entry in results'>
            <li><pre>{{entry.message}}</pre></li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="myapp.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The important parts of myapp.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json' as JSON;
import 'dart:uri' as uri;
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:web_ui/watcher.dart' as watchers;

String searchText = '';
List<LogEntry> results = [];

bool get noMatches => results.isEmpty;

void main() {
  query("#search-box").onKeyPress.listen((e) => handleKeyPress(e));
}

void handleKeyPress(KeyboardEvent e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    doSearch();
  }
}

void doSearch() {
  if (searchText != '') {
    makeRequest();
  }
}


void makeRequest() {
  HttpRequest.getString( 'http://url.to/rest-api?q=$searchText' )
    .then(processString)
    .catchError(handleError)
    ;
}

processString(String jsonString) {
  List<Map> logs = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  results.clear();
  results.addAll( logs.map((l) => new AppEntry.fromJson(l)) );
  watchers.dispatch();
}

handleError(Error error) {
  print('Request failed');
  print(error);
}

class AppEntry {
  final String message;
  AppEntry.fromJson(Map json) : message = json['message'];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `watchers.dispatch()` explicitly whenever you need to change the model in a way which is not triggered by events fired by the templates. This means AJAX calls like in your example, timers, etc.

Events installed by templates take care of calling `dispatch()` for you, so you don't have to do it in that case.

You can find more about this [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/misc/ONYKbW3xPSY).

However, at the moment, `watchers.dispatch` is treated as 'old way', as one of the goals in Web-UI is to make binding more declarative with observables. So the future-proof solution would be to use [`@observable`](http://observables-articles.dart-lang.appspot.com/web-ui/observables/) annotation on your model. This will ensure that observers are updated every time the model changes, without needing you to explicitly update them.